# metadata configuration of fields in ExtJS DirectStore

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to load grid data from a ExtDirect router. The results contain a metaData object that should reconfigure the store's fields. I am getting the following error however when I try to load my data:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortType' of undefined (ext-all-debug.js:23943)
```

The JSON result is:

```
{
    "action": "Dashboard",
    "method": "dashboarddata",
    "type": "rpc",
    "result": {
        "success": true,
        "metaData": {
            "sortInfo": {
                "direction": "ASC",
                "field": "id"
            },
            "fields": [{
                "mapping": "id",
                "id": "id"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "owner",
                "id": "owner"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "name",
                "id": "name"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "type",
                "id": "type"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "strategy",
                "id": "strategy"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "primebroker",
                "id": "primebroker"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "startdate",
                "id": "startdate"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "date_afc_prelim_approval",
                "id": "date_afc_prelim_approval"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "date_afc_approval",
                "id": "date_afc_approval"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "date_submit_regulator",
                "id": "date_submit_regulator"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "date_approval_regulator",
                "id": "date_approval_regulator"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "enddate",
                "id": "enddate"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "main_iso_currency",
                "id": "main_iso_currency"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "nav_frequency",
                "id": "nav_frequency"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "date_first_nav",
                "id": "date_first_nav"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "launch_size",
                "id": "launch_size"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "target_size",
                "id": "target_size"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "memo",
                "id": "memo"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "isin_codes",
                "id": "isin_codes"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "status",
                "id": "status"
            }],
            "totalProperty": "total",
            "successProperty": "success",
            "idProperty": "id",
            "root": "data"
        },
        "data": [{
            "status": "Project closed",
            "strategy": "Strategy X",
            "date_afc_approval": "2010-01-01",
            "startdate": "2010-01-01",
            "nav_frequency": "Bi-monthly",
            "date_first_nav": "2010-01-01",
            "enddate": "2010-01-01",
            "date_approval_regulator": "2010-01-01",
            "id": "1",
            "date_afc_prelim_approval": "2010-01-01",
            "isin_codes": "123",
            "target_size": "2000",
            "owner": "Some name",
            "name": "First project",
            "memo": "TEXTEXTEXT",
            "main_iso_currency": "TND",
            "primebroker": "Yes",
            "date_submit_regulator": "2010-01-01",
            "launch_size": "1000",
            "type": "TypeX"
        }],
        "total": 1
    },
    "tid": 6
}
```

The store itself is configured like:

```
var store = new Ext.data.DirectStore({
        idProperty: 'id'
        ,paramsAsHash: true
        ,directFn: MyApp.Direct.Dashboard.dashboarddata
        ,root:'data'
        ,autoLoad: false
        ,totalProperty:'total'
        ,fields: [
            {name: 'id', mapping: 'id'},
            {name: 'type', mapping: 'type'}
        ]
        ,baseParams: {
            type: this.type,
            filters: this.filters
        }
    });
```

Can anyone please help me? This is driving me nuts, I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Rob

PS. I am using ExtJS 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Debugging did the trick.

Apparently when updating the fields through the metaData object in the JSON response you need to name the fields. ExtJS uses the name field as a lookup field internally. Strange thing is that with static configuration of a store's fields you don't need that field...

```
...
"fields": [{
                "mapping": "id",
                "name": "id",
                "id": "id"
            },
            {
                "mapping": "owner",
                "name": "owner",
                "id": "owner"
            },
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not debug that place using Chrome or Firefox debug facility? The helpful options is setting the break on exception in the Chrome.

Comment: Hm, ever tried debugging ExtJS? :) a lot of lines of code to step through. Anyway, I think it's my best shot.